# ggplot2 ignoring locale category LC_TIME?

Tags: r, ggplot2, locale

I want to plot a time series with `ggplot()`, time line created with `strptime()`.

So far ok: I am getting German abbreviations for the months on the time axis, my locale is set to `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME"="de_DE.UTF-8")`. When I do `months()` with my data, they show up in German, too.

Weird: When I set my locale to  `Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME"="en_GB.UTF-8")`, `months()` will give me English months BUT `ggplot()` will continue to have GERMAN abbreviations for months on the time-axis.

I've tried some other categories of `Sys.setlocale()` but to no avail.

Where does `ggplot()` take the information about which language to choose?

Comment: Could you create a reproducible example?

Comment: Well, reproducibility depends on the system's locale. Mine is "de_DE.UTF-8". But the following will give German abbreviations for months even if locale is set to English: Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","en_GB.UTF-8"); data <- data.frame(date=strptime(sort(ISOdate(2010,sample(1:12, 40,replace=TRUE),sample(1:28,40,replace=TRUE))),format="%Y-%m-%d"),value=runif(4‌​0,10,12)); ggplot(data,aes(date,value)) + geom_point()

Answer (score 3):

I realize how late I am with this response, but I got the same problem and stumbled on your thread while looking for solution.

For me

```
Sys.setenv(LANGUAGE="en")
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
```

solved it.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to make it work is:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "en_US.UTF-8")
```

After that all ggplots have a proper date labels.

If you need to change only the time format this should suffice:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "en_US.UTF-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is a bit weird.

with a fresh workspace (e.g. after starting R) ggplot() can be affected by Sys.setlocale(). After the first drawing has been done with one dataframe setting other locales will be disregarded for that dataframe.